# Multi line Underscore Template and _.each

Tags: javascript, templates, loops, each, underscore.js

I'm getting an error when trying to parse an underscore template this is stored as a multi-line string:

```
{{ _.each(records, function(record, index) { }}\
    <tr>\
        {{ record.get("hours") }}\
    </tr>\
{{ }) }}\
```

The error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

On line 1 (the _.each line).

The syntax looks correct to me according to underscore's [docs](http://underscorejs.org).

Edit: I should note that i'm using {{ instead of <%= in my templates and that changing back to <%= doesn't fix the issue.

Edit: Here's the regex I use for evaluation:

```
// Underscore templates should use {{ variable_name }} instead of <%= variable_name =%>
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `{[`, for evaluation.

Assuming that you first [defined a regex](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to change the default symbols that underscore.js uses for evaluating, for example

```
 _.templateSettings = {
       evaluate: /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
       interpolate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g, 
       escape: /\{\{-([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
 };
```

You can then do something like

```
{[ _.each(records, function(record, index) { ]}
    <tr>
        {{ record.get("hours") }}
    </tr>
{[ },this); ]}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to work. What is the difference between using the bracket versus the brace?

Comment: Sorry, but did you define the `regex` for evaluation first? I just updated my anwser with it.

Comment: I guess my regex evaluation was incomplete. I was missing the evaluate property. I'll have to dive into underscore a bit more to study it. I had no idea that existed. Thanks!

Comment: I remember having the same problem when I started using it, I actually don't see the `regex` for evaluation right now in the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: Hi, this worked for me `/\{\{((?:.|\s)+?)\}\}/g` . I tested it in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3fbge)

Comment: @JeancarloFontalvo with your regex you would need to print out all of the html which is probably not what you want if your using a template. Additionally It also doesn't really match up to the default underscore template options.

Comment: Oh well, you're right Mister @Jack .  I just use it when I write multiline templates. And yeah, I supposed that the default underscore template options where with curly braces .

Comment: @JeancarloFontalvo Actually the default underscore delimiters are not with curly braces but rather *ERB-style*, the curly braces are *mustache-style*. What I meant by the default underscore template options is **interpolate**,  **escape** and **evaluate**. None of which are *multi-line* so when overriding them you probably want the behavior to stay the same and just the *delimiters* to change.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I use a function to switch when the template has multiline and when not ^-^